# Sparse Construct: Repeating Identity

Tags: python, scipy

say I have with `ij` being large (e.g. 5000) , the two following matrices

```
E = np.identity((ij))
oneVector = np.ones((1, ij))
```

and I need to compute

```
np.kron(E, oneVector)
```

This is quite slow and inefficient. Basically, the Kronecker product of identity and a row vector of ones is repeating the identity matrix horizontally `oneVector.size` times.

I believe that creating a sparse product would make more sense. `scipy.sparse.kron` would allow me to create that product if I had both A, B as sparse. But I don't know how to create the vector of ones as a "sparse type" matrix.

Is there a simple way to generate the sparse equivalent of `np.ones()` or is there another way I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `scipy.sparse.kron` do not have to be sparse.

```
In [31]: import numpy as np

In [32]: import scipy.sparse as sp

In [33]: ij = 4

In [34]: E = sp.identity(ij)  # Sparse identity matrix

In [35]: oneVector = np.ones((1, ij))  # Dense

In [36]: m = sp.kron(E, oneVector)  # m is sparse.

In [37]: m
Out[37]: 
<4x16 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 16 stored elements (blocksize = 1x4) in Block Sparse Row format>

In [38]: m.A
Out[38]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

P.S. Based on this comment:

> Basically, the Kronecker product of identity and a row vector of ones is repeating the identity matrix horizontally oneVector.size times.

I wonder if you meant `kron(oneVector, E)`:

```
In [39]: m = sp.kron(oneVector, E)

In [40]: m.A
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```